# Resize image in jsreport excel recipe

Tags: excel, image, image-resizing, recipe, jsreport

I need to resize images while printing them in an excel (I'm using the xlsx recipe, not the html-to-xlsx one) so that they don't overlay with the cell borders but leaves a bit of space (in html you'd call it padding).